# [object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. uncatachable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I started a little bit ago. I'm wanting to solve this but I can  not. Look look and re-search everywhere. And I see myself in the    obligation to ask. I already read all the threads on the subject, but    I do not know how to solve my case. I hope you can help me, try everything.

I'm using ionic3 - node.js 8.7:

*Slide7Page.html*

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let todo of todos | async">
      <ion-item>
        {{ todo.text }}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="right">
        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="removeTodo(todo._id)">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
        Delete
      </button>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>`
```

*Slide7.ts*

```
export class Slide7Page {
todos: Observable <any>;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public todoService: TodoServiceProvider, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
this.loadTodos();
}

loadTodos() {
 this.todos = this.todoService.getTodos();
 }

}
```

*todo-service.js*

```
public getTodos() {
return this.http.get (this.apiUrl + 'todos')}
```

*todo-routes.js*

```
app.get('/todos', (req, res) => {
Todo.find({}, (err, todos) => {
if (err)  {
return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Error while creating Todo', error: err });
 }

res.status(200).send({ success: true, result: todos });
});
});
```

*json*

{

```
"success": true,

"result": [

    {

        "_id": "5a2c488afc7dd1069841ead2",

        "created_at": "2017-12-09T20:33:14.294Z",

        "text": "Mi Primer TODO",

       "__v": 0

    }

]
```

}

Comment: From the error message it seems that you are not getting the array as result in todos. Can you log the todos output in console and see what is the output getting from API.

Comment: use this: `*ngFor="let todo of todos.result | async"`

Comment: no, it didn ´t work.
Maybe, 

loadTodos() {
 this.todos = this.todoService.getTodos();
 }


it's not the right way to call.

I can save a new text, and it is saved in the database. I can delete it using atom REST Client.

My only problem is that I can not see the "text" items in the front end.
Any other ideas on how you could call them at the front end?